# Notepad++ just crashed, I lost all data in a file, can I restore this somehow?

Tags: notepad++, crash

Was working on a PHP file what tells the server what content to display on a page, i added 72 variables all at once in each block of variables i had(72) and when i went to save it crashed and i lost all the data in my file

Comment: Duplicate, with several other solutions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158616/lost-code-lines-when-notepad-crashed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notepad++ keeps a backup in:

```
C:\Users\jake\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\backup
```

Comment: Not trying to steal your own answer. Just trying to make this a complete question / answer is all. If you want, add your own Scripton